# How to force circle ci build on master branches if commit message contains [ci skip]?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

The build is skipped when a pr that contains [ci skip] in the squashed commit, gets merged into master.

Is there a way in CircleCI to force the build to run on master? Can we ignore [ci skip] for branches?

Or do I need to ensure that upon merging I strip out [ci skip]?

Answer (score 0):

The string `[ci skip]` will need to be removed from the commit message in order for the merge to master to build.

Answer (score 0):

Simply navigate to the project's page in CircleCI and select which branch you wish to trigger automation for with the drop-down menu. Then click "Trigger Pipeline".

There are a few other ways a `[ci skip]` tag can be ignored:

- The build is associated with a forked PR
- The build is associated with a scheduled build
- The build is generated from the "Trigger a new pipeline" API endpoint
- The build is triggered via a tag
- You include it at the end of a commit body that has more than 247 characters

Sources:

- https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048785251-Why-Is-ci-skip-or-skip-ci-Not-Working-
- https://circleci.com/docs/skip-build/